# le chateliers principle

Tags: equilibrium, concentration

One of le chateliers principle is effect of concentration change :

> When the concentration of any of the reactants or products in a reaction at equilibrium is changed , the composition of equilibrium mixture changes so as to minimize the effect of concentration of changes.

So to get more products we need to decrease concentration of products. For decreasing concentration of products can we do it by adding something(example water) because it will also decrease"concentration". But I have not seen like this in my book. So can we?

Comment: Adding solvent will decrease the concentration of the products **and** the starting materials.